# General Laplacian of Gaussian kernel

Tags: python, image-processing, laplacianofgaussian

I am having difficulty implementing a Laplacian of Gaussian kernel. I have the following code and I am trying to implement a 9x9 kernel with sigma = 1.4. The kernel is shown on this link

http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/log.htm

However, my values are nothing like those in that kernel, I think my function is off. Help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
import math
pi= math.pi
log = [[0 for x in range(9)] for x in range(9)]
def genlog(log,size,o):
    for i in range(-size/2,size/2):
        for j in range(-size/2,size/2):
            log[i][j] = -(pi*o**4)**(-1)*(1-(i**2+j**2)/(2*o**2))*math.exp(-(i**2+j**2)/(2*o**2))
def printlog(log,size):
    for i in range(-size/2,size/2):
        print ' '.join(str(log[i][j]) for j in range(-size/2,size/2))

genlog(log,9,1.4)
printlog(log,9)
```

Comment: I don't know. What *is* wrong with your code?  In what way is it not working?  (As an aside, you probably want to be doing this with [Numpy](http://numpy.scipy.org/).)

Comment: Also, this doesn't really answer your question, because it may be that you're working on implementing this as an exercise which is fine.  But if it's for production use you may want to consider the implementation of this that's already in scipy: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_laplace.html#scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_laplace

Comment: i need log kernel, not need build-in function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laplacian of Gaussian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556958/laplacian-of-gaussian)

Comment: I had found the correct answer in math forum: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2445994/discrete-laplacian-of-gaussian-log

Answer (score 2):

the question is neraly three years old, so i don't know if it's useful, but i implemented the cited algorithm in excel and found that your function should be writed as such :

```
log[i][j] = (-1)/(pi*o**4)*(1-(i**2+j**2)/(2*o**2))*math.exp(-(i**2+j**2)/(2*o**2))
```

A scaling factor should be used, too, to account for the source image size.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on the scaling factor? How to choose it and why?

Comment: Please find my test file here (tab 3) : https://github.com/ljegou/laplacian_gaussian/blob/main/log.xlsx

Answer (score 1):

Your code is pretty hard to read to begin with, but for starters, you have:

```
log[i][j] = (pi*o**4)**.5*...
```

When it should really be, according to your formula:

```
log[i][j] = -(pi*o**4)**(-1)*...
```

Raising something to the `.5` is actually a square root.  What you're looking for is the inverse, raising it by `-1`.  Also, you forgot to make it negative.

Comment: Sorry, i had change my code, result not true, can you help me

Comment: @NamPNQ I have no idea what you mean by that.

Comment: I want send two param (size,sigma) and return laplacian of gaussion kernel like http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/figs/logdisc.gif

Comment: I don't know what that means.  You should probably send this over to Math SO.

Comment: sorry for my english is bad, i had change my question